# Prestashop:language block not show in front end in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

i downloaded latest **prestashop 1.5** version and 
i install successfully but in front side language block not showing...
i did enable module for language from admin side and set position in header but not showing in header plz give any suggestion for show in front end...

Comment: u have to check template file for language block

Comment: yes.. i did plz give more info for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fond `blocklanguages.tpl` file in blocklanguages module and check code:

```
 if count($languages) > 1
```

**replace by**

```
 if count($languages) >= 1
```

I fixed same problem by this change. I hope this helps also someone.

Comment: thnks kukadiya i also fix my issue